# Anyway to prevent rabbitmq dead letter queue dropping properties?

Tags: javascript, rabbitmq

I'm using the dead letter exchange feature on rabbitmq to perform scheduled rpc calls, but after the queue is dead lettered it dropped the replyto property that was in the original queue. Is there anyway to declare the replyto property in a way that it will be retained in the "dead queue"?

I'm doing this with amqplib in node.js by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, RabbitMQ will only preserve the properties that are listed on [the Dead Letter Exchange page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html):

- queue - the name of the queue the message was in before it was dead-lettered,
- reason - reason for DLX being used
- time - the date and time the message was dead lettered as a 64-bit AMQP format timestamp,
- exchange - the exchange the message was published to
- routing-keys - the routing keys the message was published with,
- count - how many times this message was dead-lettered in this queue for this reason, and
- original-expiration - the original expiration property of the message.

There are 2 ways to solve the problem you're seeing, I think.

1) Put the reply-to in your own header or property field, and read it from there / replace it when it's not in the usual spot

2) Don't use the reply-to field. Instead, use a well-known exchange for the reply at a later point in time.

Using the reply-to field typically implies a request/response or RPC scenario. These scenarios usually need a response fairly quickly. If a response does not come quickly, the system can usually move forward without it - even if it's just a message to the user saying "X is not available right now".

You say you're using a DLX to do scheduled RPC calls... delayed messages is a common use case for a DLX - nothing wrong with that. But delaying the RPC response can run in to some significant challenges beyond what you're already seeing.

For example, what happens when your system has a hiccup and the code that made the original request is no longer there to listen for the response? The answer to this depends on whether or not you really need the response to be handled. If you do need it to be handled - the system will run in to serious trouble if it isn't - then RPC can be dangerous.

Instead of relying on RPC and implying a temporal need for a given response, it's often better to use two-way messaging via separate queues. I've written about this in both my [managing long running processes](http://derickbailey.com/2015/08/10/managing-workflow-in-long-running-javascript-processes/) post and in my [RabbitMQ Patterns](http://derickbailey.com/email-courses/rabbitmq-patterns-for-applications/) email course / ebook.

The gist of it is that you can avoid the need for a reply-to queue by having the original message publisher also be a subscriber with a queue for the responses.

An example from the long running process post:

```
var DrinkRequestSender = new Sender(/* ... details ... */);
var DrinkRequestReceiver = new Receiver(/* ... details ... */);

var DrinkStation = {
  make: function(drink){

    DrinkRequestReceiver.receive((response) => {
      var drinkResponse = response.body;
      this.trigger("drinkup", drinkResponse);
    });

    var drinkData = drink.toJSON();
    DrinkRequestSender.send(drinkData);
  }
};
```

In this example, the code is sending out a "request" and later receiving a "response" - but not using a standard RPC setup. It is using a dedicated queue for the response, with the code on the other end sending the reply back via an exchange that routes to that queue.

This allows you to better handle failure scenarios, very long running processes and more.

This style of 2-way messaging does add some additional challenges, though. For one, you'll have to build in the ability to reconstruct the object that made the original request.

You can find this detailed in [the long running process post](http://derickbailey.com/2015/08/10/managing-workflow-in-long-running-javascript-processes/), and there's a bit more info in [RMQ Patterns](http://derickbailey.com/email-courses/rabbitmq-patterns-for-applications/), as well (along with a lot of other patterns).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Derick! I shall try your suggestion :)